# Is there a way to display a UIBarButtonItem without using a UIToolBar... or even

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Or even, is it posible to make the UIToolbar invisible?

How can I achieve the effect of showing a standard UIBarButtonItem, without showing a UIToolBar?

Comment: hmm.. I cannot imagine what do you want to do, really. what is wrong with standard UIButtons? just set their style to custom and use any picture you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UISegmentedControl` with just one segment and `segmentedControlStyle` set to `UISegmentedControlStyleBar` might help you.

Comment: Close enough for a demo :)

Thanks!

Comment: UISegmentedControl requires at least 2 buttons, but +1 for the creativity